# How should I decide which duplicate to close?

Tags: discussion, best-practice, vote-to-close

Should I vote to close strictly the newest one, or the one that has the most constructive content?

What if both have constructive content, as is the case with these two questions?

- [bind software to different network interfaces](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4872/bind-software-to-different-network-interfaces)
- [How can an application (like Firefox) be forced to use a certain network interface?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/25778/how-can-an-application-like-firefox-be-forced-to-use-a-certain-network-interfac)

Comment: I'm fairly sure I've asked a question on here that could be a duplicate of these too.

Comment: My question states "A wrapper like example-wrapper eth0 program is fine too if such program exist. I'd like to avoid IPTables solutions if possible.". So a nifty hacked script that configures IP Tables would be fine too. I won't accept a "no" for that question ;)

Answer (score 6):

If both questions have good content, they should be *Merged* rather than closed.

Otherwise, you should vote to close the one that's worse. Which can be defined in a few different ways. I'll try to put them in ascending order of importance (this is my opinion, nothing more):

1. Has poor quality answers (one clinches the deal, as far as I'm concerned)
2. Is less general, less *canonical*
3. Has fewer or no answers
4. Is older, or concerning an outdated version of some software
5. The OP is inactive, the question isn't edited
6. Has fewer views (that's "other")

Most of the time, it'll be obvious to you which one deserves to stay. And hopefully, as we discourage answering duplicates, the newer question won't have better answers by the time you see it.

Answer (score 5):

In this case (between these two questions) I'd be inclined to leave both as they are. One is dealing with two distinct applications (a browser and not a browser) and the other is dealing with two browsers. There are several technique of doing what they're asking the if it's the same protocol, that cuts off some options and opens up others.

It's a pretty technical difference but it's similar (in my mind) to the reason we don't merge every "Help my wireless isn't working" question.

Annoyingly their answers are probably the wrong way around (I'd recommend SOCKS to dierre and iproute to Lekensteyn).

Answer (score 0):

Close the question who's posted date is greater than the other post.